# Motivation behind the proeprties of sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

What is the motivation behind the class $B$ of all measurable sets to satisfy the following properties :

1) $A_1, A_2 \in B$ implies $A_1 \cup A_2 \in B$

2) $\{A_n\} \in B $ and $\{A_n\}$ is increasing then $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \in B$

Answer (score 1):

Basically the idea behind sigma-algebras is this.  We'd like to be able to assign measures or probabilities to sets, but it turns out we can't do that for every set.  So we try to do the best we can, getting at least enough to handle the kinds of sets that arise in practice.  Starting with, say, the open sets and using the operations of complements, finite unions and countable increasing unions gives you the Borel sets, which are enough: you will never encounter a non-Borel set in "real life".

Comment: I thought the reason is like this : suppose we know the measure of some familiar sets (such as triangle, circle etc.) and we want to approximate an unknown shaped area using them, then in order to define the limit I need increasing/decearsing sets. Is it correct ?

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the sigma-algebra as the "events" that are possible on your sample space. It pretty much says that if you have two events, then either of those events occurring is also an event. The second says similar but for an infinite sequence of increasing events, the limit must also be an event.